# Sometimes when i try download file to ftp I get error: 550 Access is denied. But sometimes all is work

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to upload files from a folder "msg" to a server. Sometimes I get an error “550 Access is denied”, sometimes everything works. The error occurs on the line: ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + files[i], my_file) . Timeout does not help to fix the error. Can someone advise how to fix this ?

```
if ping('*.*.*.*')!=0:
    if os.listdir("msg"):
        ftp = FTP('*.*.*.*')
        ftp.login('****','****')
        files = os.listdir("msg")
        for i in range (len(files)):
            my_file=open("msg\\"+files[i], "rb")
            ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + files[i], my_file)
            my_file.close()
        ftp.quit()
```

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration issue

Comment: It is a permissions problem on the server-side. The FTP user account does not have permission to either create a new file, or overwrite an existing file, in the current remote directory.

Comment: when you run the script multiple times, the files are downloaded to the server. I had an idea that the script starts to download files before I got the connection, but I do not know how to check it

Comment: *"I had an idea that the script starts to download files before I got the connection"* - That's not the case. It's rather that the file is locked by some process on the server (the file is still being created/written to, or being checked by an antivirus).

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. Thanks to all users who help me with it. The problem was ridiculously simple. On my server stored a file created when you create a server directly on it. Since I was trying to add and download a lot of files at once I did not notice that I did not have the ability to edit this file. The essence of the problem and its solution was found with the help of step-by-step execution of the program.